# Why is "Replication monitoring refresher for distribution" disabled by default?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, database-replication

When you set up a new publication on SQL Server 2008 in SQL Server Management Studio, it sets up a bunch of related jobs in SQL Server Agent.  By default, all of them are enabled for me except for "Replication monitoring refresher for distribution", which is disabled by default.  Why is it disabled?  As far as I can tell it's supposed to be enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's OK. This job runs continuously, but without job schedule, so it seems like disabled. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152482(v=sql.105).aspx